# operand expected (error token is “+ ”): Bash error when adding array element value to numerical variable

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, syntax-error

I have been working on a bash script to generate a script for duplicating a database on a different (auxiliary) server.

There are 6 locations on the auxiliary host where the files will be stored (hence the for loop `0 >= i >=5`).

The scripts main purpose is to check that the auxiliary host's locations have enough space to accommodate the files which will be copied across.

- `aux_dest_space` is space available on mounted locations on auxiliary host; where the files are to be stored (array).
- `temp_space` is file size(s) (cumulative); in order for the copy process to stop once aux_dest_space is full.
- `df_size` is file size (stored in array)

**Error Message:**

```
./script.sh: line 108: 472879112 +  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+  ")
temp_space=$(( $temp_space + ${df_size[${k}]} ))
```

My code:

```
for (( i=0; i<=5; i++ ))
do
      while [ ${aux_dest_space[${i}]} -gt $temp_space ]
      do
          .
          .
          .
          .
           k=$((k+1))
           temp_space=$(( $temp_space + ${df_size[${k}]} )) # (line 108 - error)
       done
       temp_space=${df_size[${k}]}
 done
```

Comment: What gives `echo ${df_size[${k}]}` just before the error? I assume it's empty.

Comment: Did you initialize `temp_space` before the loop? If not, the variable is empty

Comment: @pfnuesel
./script.sh: line 105: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./script.sh: line 112: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp_space=0
for (( i=0; i<=5; i++ ))
do
      while [ ${aux_dest_space[${i}]} -gt $temp_space ]
      do
          .
          .
          .
          .
          k=$((k+1))
          temp_space=$(( temp_space + df_size[${k}] )) # (line 108 - error)
      done
      temp_space=${df_size[${k}]}
done
```

I had to remove the dollar sign and the curly brackets from line 108; which gave the error.

Comment: That's because `df_size[$k]` was empty or uninitialized. Without the dollar sign, if it's empty or uninitialized, it's treated as 0. It seems that pfnuesel's assumption (in comment in OP) was correct.

Comment: It was initialised as 
df_size=($(awk -F "," '{print $3}' file_list.csv))
If it hadn't been initialised there would be no use for it in the loop.

I am "assuming" that it has to do with the fact that it exists in an arithmetic expression - $(()).  Not sure about this but just guessing.

Comment: Can you confirm that `df_size` was really initialized as you say? can you add `declare -p df_size` before the loop, and check that the fields you're using are really non-empty, and/or put `printf '%q\n' "${df_size[$k]}"` before using it?

Comment: Also, to track the error, you can add `set -x` just before the culprit line, and `set +x` just after.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$temp_space` to zero before the loop:

```
temp_space=0
for (( i=0; i<=5; i++ ))
do
      while [ ${aux_dest_space[${i}]} -gt $temp_space ]
      do
          .
          .
          .
          .
           k=$((k+1))
           temp_space=$(( $temp_space + ${df_size[${k}]} )) # (line 108 - error)
       done
       temp_space=${df_size[${k}]}
 done
```

Comment: If that would be the problem, it would already throw an error at `[ ${aux_dest_space[${i}]} -gt $temp_space ]`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Barmar.  I initialise $temp_space as: 
`temp_space=${df_size[0]}`

Comment: Oh, the problem is that you're going beyond the end of the `df_size` array. It goes from 0 to 5. On the last iteration, when `$i` is 5, you set `$k` to 6, and then try to access `${df_size[6]}`, which doesn't exist. I don't understand the logic of your loop, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Barmar; I tried to keep my post as simple and little as possible - which is probably causing problems since not all info is here.  There are over 50 datafiles.  Their size value is stored in the array df_size.

Comment: Whatever it is, the problem is that you're going beyond the end of the array when you set `$k` to `$i+1`.